# C++ Delete and Compact even rows in 2D dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, 2d

i need some help

This program must do:

•Delete all the even rows

•Compact the remaining rows tothe top of the 2D array

https://gyazo.com/64954d5a5ace39e7bb4264f2e2a9ecdf

CODE:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
   int ** array2d;

   int size = 10;
   array2d = new int *[size];
   cout << "***** Before Compaction ******" << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      array2d[i] = new int[size];
      cout << "ROW " <<i << ":";
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
         array2d[i][j] = i;
         cout << " "<< array2d[i][j];
      }
      cout << endl;
   }

   //NEED HELP WITH THIS PART DOWN HERE


   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) { // delete the even rows
         delete[] array2d[i];
         array2d[i] = NULL;
      }
      // for each row in the first half, redirect the pointer
      // to the next odd row
      if(i<size/2){
         array2d[i] = array2d[2 * i + 1];
         array2d[2 * i + 1] = NULL;

      }

      cout << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (i % 2 == 0) { // delete the even rows
     delete[] array2d[i];
     array2d[i] = NULL;
  }
```

`i == 0` corresponds to the first line. I think you may want to change that to:

```
  if ((i+1) % 2 == 0) { // delete the even rows
     delete[] array2d[i];
     array2d[i] = NULL;
  }
```

And then,

```
     array2d[i] = array2d[2 * i + 1];
     array2d[2 * i + 1] = NULL;
```

needs to be:

```
     array2d[i] = array2d[2 * i];
     array2d[2 * i] = NULL;
```

**Update**

The problem with what you have and what I suggested is that you are leaking memory. When you use:

```
     array2d[i] = array2d[2 * i];
```

the memory allocated for `array2d[i]` is lost. You have no way of deallocating that memory. You may want to swap the pointer values to allow you to deallocate all the memory.

```
     int* temp = array2d[i];
     array2d[i] = array2d[2 * i];
     array2d[2 * i] = temp;
```

Comment: How would I format the cout to re-print the new array

Comment: @JohnDoubie, Same as before except that make sure the check for `i` is `i < size/2`.

Comment: Thanks for the response i cannot get it to print out an error

Comment: @JohnDoubie, that seems unrelated to your original post.